# Regex to find a space or comma in a lookahead

Tags: regex, excel, regex-lookarounds

I did look around but I couldn't find an answer which had what I needed. Apologies in advance as I am currently teaching myself regex (using VB in excel) and I think I am having a syntax problem.

What I want:
To find all 5 digit numbers in a text document, to associate them with a date and to print them to an excel spreadsheet.

What I am getting:
A single instance of that number, per set, to each date.

What I think is wrong:
My regex pattern definition. I want to find a 5 digit number that can have a comma or space following the number.

```
oRegEx.Pattern = "\d{5}(?=([\s]*)|[,])"
```

I'm pretty confident that is the issue here and I'm also sure it is syntactical in nature, but I am so new to this I don't know what I am doing wrong. I've posted my entire code below.

```
Public Sub ParseMail()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Dim oFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim oFile As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim sHeaderDate As String
    Dim sIDList As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim oRegEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    Dim oMatches As Object

    Set oFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set oFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\source doc.txt", ForReading) 'Open the exported file. Change path as needed.
    Set oRegEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp 'Instantiate RegEx object

    oRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    oRegEx.Pattern = "\d{5}(?=([\s]*)|[,])" 'Regular expression to identify 5 digit numbers... not working well."


    i = 1 ' init variable to 1. This is the first row to start writing in spreadsheet.

    Do While Not oFile.AtEndOfStream ' Read the file until it reaches the end.
        sTemp = oFile.ReadLine 'Get the first line
        'Debug.Print sTemp
        If Left(sTemp, 5) = "Sent:" Then 'Look for the date in the header.
            sHeaderDate = Mid(sTemp, 7) 'set this variable starting at pos 7 of this line.
            'Debug.Print sHeaderDate
        Else
            'This is not the date header so start checking for IDs.
            Set oMatches = oRegEx.Execute(sTemp)
            If Not oMatches Is Nothing Then 'Find anything?
              If oMatches.Count > 0 Then
                        For x = 0 To oMatches.Count - 1 'walk thru all found values and write to active spreadsheet.
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = sHeaderDate
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = oMatches(x)
                            i = i + 1

                        Next
                    End If
                End If

            End If
    Loop

    oFile.Close

    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oRegEx = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide sample text

Comment: I had to redact a large portion of the text. The file itself is very large.

Comment: From: name@email.com
Sent: Thursday, November 07, 2013 2:15 PM
To: name@email.com
Subject: VERIFICATION IS REQUIRED - 

Importance: High




You must contact the Package originator to have the Package re-sent via SAFE to other users.

Your Package has not yet been sent. 

https://www.website.com


If you did not send these files, please notify name@email.com ASAP.

You have uploaded the following file(s): 81575, 83288.

CT: 2

Package ID: 1953645

The file will be available until 11/21/2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regex that matches five digits followed by either a **space** or a comma, try:

```
\d{5}(?=[ ,])
```

or if you really want any whitespace character:

```
\d{5}(?=[\s,])
```

Note the space in the lookahead.  \s, which you used, will match any whitespace character, but those include more than just the **space**.

In your regex, you use

```
(?=([\s]*)|[,])
```

So first you lookahead for a whitespace character that occurs zero or more times -- since the character may frequently occur **zero** times, you may not be matching what you expect.

With regard to your code:

```
oRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
```

is irrelevant, but you need to add

```
oRegEx.Global = True
```

in order to collect all the matches.

Comment: This resolves my syntax question- and thanks for that (really, thanks). However, my overarching problem of only pulling the first "instance" of a 5 digit number remains. Do you have any suggestions? In the sample I provided, as an example, I only see 81575, but not 83288.

Comment: @ChrisW., in your sample text, `83288` isn't followed by a comma or space. It's followed by a period, so it doesn't match.

Comment: @BrianStephens When I modify my code to include periods, I am still unable to see the second instance, in this case 83288, on my print screen (in this case, excel). I'm wondering if there isn't a larger problem with my code that is causing such laziness. Everything I read indicates that regex is greedy.

Comment: You need to set the Global property of your Regular Expression object to TRUE.  Otherwise it will only match the first.  By the way, for a regex, why not simply "\b\d{5}\b"

Comment: I edited my response to show the need for setting the Global property.

Comment: The global property was the issue. Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 1):

your regex to find all 5 digit numbers (and 5 digits only) would be

```
oRegEx.Pattern = "\b\d{5}\b"
```

`\b` is a word boundary and `\d{5}` matches 5 digits

you can test this out [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cb%5Cd%7B5%7D%5Cb&input=From%3a%20name@email.com%20Sent%3a%20Thursday,%20November%2007,%202013%202:15%20PM%20To%3a%20name@email.com%20Subject%3a%20VERIFICATION%20IS%20REQUIRED%20-%20Importance%3a%20High%20You%20must%20contact%20the%20Package%20originator%20to%20have%20the%20Package%20re-sent%20via%20SAFE%20to%20other%20users.%20Your%20Package%20has%20not%20yet%20been%20sent.%20website.com%20If%20you%20did%20not%20send%20these%20files,%20please%20notify%20name@email.com%20ASAP.%20You%20have%20uploaded%20the%20following%20file%28s%29%3a%2081575,%2083288.%20CT%3a%202%20Package%20ID%3a%201953645%20The%20file%20will%20be%20available%20until%2011/21/2013)

Comment: This answer is very similar to Brian's in that it 100% resolves my syntax problem (and again, thank you for that) but when I run my code with your suggested modifications to my pattern, I still only receive the first applicable response. IE from my example, I am able to see 81575, but not 83288. Any suggestions on this? I'm sorry if I am being to needy here, but I have so little clue as to what I'm doing it's probably an obvious fix and I just don't know.

Comment: what does oMatches.Count give you as an answer?

Comment: It shows only 1 match. Which is mind boggling- because when I run just the regex without my print functions it pulls 2.